# what is meaning of a negative numa node id?

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, out-of-memory, numa

I have a memory error on my custom imx board. It uses a single core cortex A72 Soc runnning linux kernel 5.4.47

```
SLUB: Unable to allocate memory on node -1, gfp=0xb21(GFP_ATOMIC|GFP_DMA|__GFP_ZERO)
```

What is the meaning of a negative numa node id? I usually get node 0 in my oom indicating one numa node mapped to type DMA32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node `-1` corresponds to value of the macro `NUMA_NO_NODE`.

Usually this value means request for memory from the node for **current CPU**.